# Alpha anywhere: Can I populate JSON data into the list

Tags: json, list

Can I populate a list with JSON data? I have a general list containing data available for several sessions but I need to filter them with my current session and insert them to another list. My idea is to use the filtered JSON data since I successfully filtered them in JSON format. I've looked into some threads that might relate but currently get nothing. Hope someone can point me to the right page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this page: or maybe I overlooked it: https://forum.alphasoftware.com/showthread.php?119524-How-to-populate-a-List-from-a-JSON-formatted-field.
Anyway, populating JSON data into list in alpha anywhere is easy to be done. Firstly, get the JSON data(in my case I produce them from another list). With this data(already in JSON format), I do the filter using:

`var filtered_json = find_in_object(JSON.parse('my_JSON_data'), {my_filter_condition});`

Then, the result should be in `[object object][object object]`

Finally, populate the result to the list.

```
var lObj= {dialog.object}.getControl('my_list_ID')
lObj.populate(filtered_json);
```